# wp_insert_post issue

Tags: wp-insert-post

I've got the following code in the 'functions.php' file of a wordpress theme

```
$ppost_data = build_post( $pID, $pcontent, $pname, $ptitle, $pstatus, $ptype, $pset_comment_status );

wp_insert_post($ppost_data);
```

and here's the 'build_post()' function:

```
function build_post( $pID, $pcontent, $pname, $ptitle, $pstatus, $ptype, $pset_comment_status ) {
return array(
    'ID'=>$pID,
    'post_content'=>$pcontent,
    'post_name'=>$pname,
    'post_title'=>$ptitle,
    'post_status'=>$pstatus,
    'post_type'=>$ptype,
    'comment_status'=>$pset_comment_status,
    'post_author' => 1
);
```

The variables are all set, and all of the data is in the `$ppost_data` array correctly, but the page isn't being added. No errors are being thrown. Any ideas?

Comment: where does `$pID` come from? If it's not the ID of an existing post, the function will fail.

Comment: Milo beat me to it.  If you pass an id, you are implying an update.  Don't pass one to tell the function to create a post.

Comment: Milo wins! Thanks for your help guys. Milo, if you'll post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting a new post, you must omit or leave the `ID` parameter empty, or the post will not be inserted. You can only set the `ID` if you are updating an existing post with that ID.

See [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) in Codex for more information.